# Random redirects in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, redirect, angular2-routing

I have running into a strange situation where everynow and then my angular app seems to do some random redirects.

I have a notes section that when you add a new note it should add the note to the notes list(no redirect in the code). But for some reasons when a user first logs in and they create their first note(this only happens on the first one, all consecutive notes work as expected).

The redirect also adds some funny params to the URL `http://localhost:4200/phils-test-team/goals?body=redirects%2Bto%2Bgoals&title=&title=`

This `?body=redirects%2Bto%2Bgoals&title=&title=` is not in the code.

When I check my console and enable route tracing all looks correct.

I guess the question is, are there particular things in angular that are known to effect redirects or could cause redirects without specifying them in the code.

New-Note.Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'new-note',
  templateUrl: './new-note.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-note.component.styl']
})
export class NewNoteComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() initialValue:any;
  experiment_id: string;
  goal_id: string;
  user_id: string;
  team_id: string;
  form: FormGroup;
  date_created: any;

  isActive = false;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private notesService: NotesService,
    private usersService: UsersService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isActive = false;
    this.date_created = new Date();

    this.route.parent.data.map((d: any) => d.experiment).subscribe((experiment: any) => {
      this.user_id = experiment.user_id;
      this.team_id = experiment.team_id;
      this.goal_id = experiment.goal_id;
      this.experiment_id = experiment.$key;
    });

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      body: ['',Validators.required],
      date_modified: new Date(),
      customer: [''],
      company: ['']
      // rating: ['',Validators.required]
    });

    console.log(this.form);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['initialValue']) {
      this.form.patchValue(changes['initialValue'].currentValue);

      this.experiment_id = this.team_id;
    }
  }

  isErrorVisible(field:string, error:string) {

    return this.form.controls[field].dirty
      && this.form.controls[field].errors &&
      this.form.controls[field].errors[error];
  }

  reset() {
    this.form.reset();
  }


  get valid() {
    return this.form.valid;
  }

  get value() {
    return this.form.value;
  }

  // Toggle Add Note
  onToggleAddNote() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  save(form, onToggleAddNoteInActive) {
    this.notesService.createNewNote(this.team_id, this.user_id, this.goal_id, this.experiment_id, form.value, this.date_created)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          // alert("note created succesfully. Create another note ?");
          form.reset();
          this.isActive = false;
        },
        err => alert(`error creating note ${err}`)
      );
  }

}
```

App.Routes

```
export const routerConfig: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'teams/new',
    component: NewTeamComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'home', redirectTo: '/login'
  },
  {
    path: ':team-name',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: {
      team: TeamResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'goals',
        children: [
          { path: ':goal_id', component: SingleGoalComponent,
            resolve: {
              goal: GoalResolver
            },
            children: [
              { path: 'experiments/new', component: NewExperimentComponent },
              { path: 'experiments/:experiment_id',
                resolve: {
                  experiment: ExperimentResolver
                },
                children: [
                  { path: 'edit', component: EditExperimentComponent,
                  },
                  { path: '', component: ExperimentDetailsComponent,
                    children: [
                      { path: 'notes', component: ExperimentNotesComponent },
                      { path: '', component: BlankNotesComponent }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              { path: '', component: ExperimentsComponent }
            ]
          },
          { path: '', component: GoalsComponent }
        ]
      },
      { path: 'notes', component: NotesComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: '',  redirectTo: '/login',  pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**',  redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

Update:
I noticed that it's actually taking the content of the form and adding it to the URL.

```
http://localhost:4800/phils-test-team/goals?body=new%2Bgoal%2Bshould%2Bbe%2Badded%2Bwith%2Bout%2Bany%2Bproblems&title=&title=
```

Update:
new-note.component.html

```
<div class="add-note" [class.is-active]="isActive">
  <button class="add-note-button" (click)="onToggleAddNote()">
    Add Note
    <md-icon svgSrc="assets/images/plus-circle-outline.svg"></md-icon>
  </button>

  <div class="add-note-content">
    <form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off" novalidate class="note-form">

      <fieldset>

        <div class="form-field">
          <textarea name="body" formControlName="body"></textarea>
          <div class="field-error-message"
               *ngIf="isErrorVisible('body', 'required')">
            field is mandatory
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <div class="btn-group actions">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="onToggleAddNote()">
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="save(form)">
              Save
            </button>
          </div>

        </div>

      </fieldset>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does the form HTML look like? Do you import `FormsModule` and/or `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: I am using `ReactiveFormsModule` will add the form to the above code if it helps.